# Angular: modules exports does not come up

Tags: angular

Consider the following modules structure:

*page-content.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PageContentComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        PageContentComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
})
export class PageContentModule { }
```

*markup.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        PageContentModule,
    ]
})
export class MarkupModule { }
```

So I have **MarkupModule**, that imports **PageContentModule** that eventually exports **PageContentComponent**.

Now, I create a new **PageComponent** component along with **PageModule**, where I want to use the **PageContentComponent**

page.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PageComponent],
  bootstrap: [PageComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MarkupModule,
  ]
})
export class PageModule { }
```

And here is a problem, by importing **MarkupModule**, I assume that **PageContentModule** will be imported as well, along with its *exports* option. But it does not happen, compiler says that

> **"page-content" is not a known element**

And I have to import **PageContentModule**

The question is - did I get it wrong and this is how it should be, or there a mistake somewhere in the code. I imply that if I import **MarkupModule** - all submodules should be imported as well, exposing all the exported components.

Comment: Isn't it confusing? MarkupModule is importing PageModule, and PageModule is importing MarkupModule. Are you sure about this circular dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should export PageModule in MarkupModule via exports: [....., PageModule]
Because each module has it's own scope, and it's not re-exporting other modules by default.